# reverse string bus error

Tags: c++, string, reverse

I'm doing some basic c++ and decided to implement a revStr method.

But for some reason every time I execute the method, I  get a bus error caused by the assignments in the while loop but I can't understand why.

Anybody got any clues? Any help would be much appreciated.

```
char* reverseStr(char* s){
    if(!s){
        cout << "Void!"<<endl;
        return s;
    }

    char* end, *start;
    end = s;
    start = s;

    while(*(end) != '\0'){
        end++;
    }
    end--;


    while(start < end){
        char temp = *start;
        cout << temp <<endl;
        *start = *end;
        *end = temp;
        start++;
        end--;
    }

    cout << "The reversed string is: " << s <<endl;
    return s;

}
```

Apologies.. I have added the driver program below:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

assert(reverseChar("hello") == "olleh");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Start with formatting your code correctly, also show a [MCVE] please. I'd suspect you're passing some string literal as `char* s` that actually can't be altered by your code.

Comment: Did you, perhaps, pass a string literal when you called it (e.g., `reverseStr("Some input");` or a pointer to a string literal (e.g., `char *s = "This is a string"; reverseStr(s);`? Either of those will give undefined behavior.

Comment: Your function is altering the data pointed by `s`. If that is a string literal, data is read only, so you cannot change it, so you probably get an exception.

Comment: You cannot modify a constant, that's what make them constant.

Comment: unable to reproduce ... code works as expected.

Comment: I added the driver program thats producing the behaviour

Answer (score 0):

If you're passing a string literal it should not compile as your func (correctly) takes non-const.
Unless, of course, you force cast it... so don't remove the const but `strdup()` it instead.

What could also be happening is that the loop runs forever. You can test it with a debugger.

The reason is that pointers cannot be properly compared for less, or greater then. Only for equality. You have to change your `<` to `!=`

Answer (score 0):

Unable to reproduce problem ... code works as expected.

My Test (showing how I created "forwardCharStar[100]);")

```
int t282(void)
{
   std::string  forwardStr = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
   size_t sz =  forwardStr.size();

   assert(sz < 100); // check fit
   //          ^^^-----------vvv
   char      forwardCharStar[100];

   for (size_t i = sz-1; i < 100; ++i) forwardCharStar[i] = 0;
   for (size_t i = 0; i < sz; ++i)     forwardCharStar[i] = forwardStr[i];

   std::string rS = reverseStr(forwardCharStar);

   std::cout << "The reversed string is: " << rS << std::endl;

   return (0);
}
```

Note: filled tail of forwardCharStar[100] with '\0' 
         - null terminator is important in c-style strings

Note: then transferred 26 chars from 'forwardStr' to front of forwardCharStar

Output:

```
The reversed string is: zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba
```

Note: I commented out the char by char output from 
      2nd line of while loop

```
     // std::cout << temp << std::endl;
```

Note: forwardCharStar[100] matches the reversed string, the code modifies its input string.